# Indices repair stopped by error

Tags: upgrade

I stuck with the error. When I try to repair indices I get error message:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_entity_id_entity_table_account_relationship ON 
civicrm_entity_financial_account (entity_id, entity_table, 
account_relationship) [nativecode=1062 ** Duplicate entry '0-
civicrm_financial_type-12' for key 
'index_entity_id_entity_table_account_relationship']
[type] => DB_Error
```

If I look into table see no problems.

Comment: What means: 0-civicrm_financial_type-12

I Checked the table no duplicate for first sight on 'civicrm_financial_type' field values.

Comment: When you say no problems, do you mean no duplicate rows?

Comment: I found it in rows: 

27,civicrm_financial_type,0,12,15

28,civicrm_financial_type,0,12,16

Now what next?

Comment: I found it The "0-s" is wrong values. They must be 4, and 2. The index value must be 1 or above. Can I change it?

Comment: Well, that explains why you could not create the index, and you can retry it after the update. I do not know if the new values are functionally correct. But you did some research.

Comment: I researched the other tables, linked to this table and found these values as good as possible, Changed it, now can run indices update, finish it, but the 'Update indices' warning remains in System Status page. More work on it. But this problem solved.

Comment: I summarized this discussion in an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing the discussion from the comments.

1. The error indicates that the table contains a duplicate row.
2. After the row was updated the index could be created.
3. To find the correct values for the row was done by examining the linked tables.